# android:screenOrientation=“sensorPortrait" not valid?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-orientation

I need to limit my app to displaying in portrait mode.

Using **android:screenOrientation=“Portrait"** works great but I'd like to have the display change to reverse portrait when the device is rotated.

Using **android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"** results in a compile error. 
Funny thing though, if I use "sensorLandscape" instead it compiles fine but it's not what I need.

I'm using Eclipse v 3.7.2 with Android 2.3.3

Any ideas???

Thanks
Rob

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'sensorPortrait').

Comment: That is odd. I personally don't know what's happening, I can only say make sure you have spelled it right and try cleaning your project...

Comment: Cleaning didn't help. I wonder if "sensorPortrait" has been misspelled in a definition table (or whatever)? Do you know if I can specify the numeric value (7) instead of a string?

Comment: Thanks Alex!!!  I was on the right track wondering if it was a typo. I wonder if Google will leave it misspelled or fix it in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google has made a typo, use **sensorPortait**